# Filter only with capacitor

Tags: capacitor, filter

I have some questions about capacitor and the circuit shown below:

[image]

The original signal including noise is shown below:

[image]

There are three waveforms shown in one picture.

The top one, middle one, and last one is connected to 4.7µF, 0.1µF, and 100µF respectively. Why is the top one smoother than middle one? Why is the last one out of shape and attenuated? If I change GND to 2.5V, is it able to filter out the noise? If I can filter out the noise only with capacitor, why using RC?

[image]

Comment: Your source/load ratio of impedance  defines this slope change.

Comment: For the same reason you use a clutch on a car as opposed to revving up and crashing the gears without a clutch.

Comment: Obviously your source is not ideal.   Is it a buffered signal generator with 2.5V DC bias?  Every part has some resistance. Even your source and the capacitor. It is the nonlinear ratio that causes distortion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your distortion is due to source unable to drive as much current  for positive waves.
But I will not guess your source.

All capacitors uses electrodes and the surface area and chemical bond determines the effective series resistance , which can load AC waveforms which changes the slope of the voltage and the peak amplitude.

Usually that's a good thing but it all depends on the driving current-limited source-resistance ratio to load capacitive impedance and it's internal ESR.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f51w5N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Although I could guess why out positive wave slope reduces with higher resistance, [let's see here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2053%205%2050%0Ar%20176%2032%20336%2032%200%20100%0Ac%20336%2032%20336%2096%200%201e-7%201.043475991881134%0Av%2080%20288%2080%20160%200%201%2080%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20176%20128%20336%20128%200%20100%0Ac%20336%20128%20336%20192%200%200.00001%202.7534946850574133%0Ac%20336%20224%20336%20288%200%200.001%200.09484663771640765%0Ar%20176%20224%20336%20224%200%20100%0Aw%20336%2032%20416%2032%200%0Aw%20336%2096%20416%2096%200%0Aw%20336%20128%20416%20128%200%0Aw%20336%20192%20416%20192%200%0Aw%20336%20224%20416%20224%200%0Aw%20336%20288%20416%20288%200%0Ap%20416%2032%20416%2096%201%204%0Ap%20416%20128%20416%20192%201%204%0Ap%20416%20224%20416%20288%201%204%0Ar%2080%20160%2080%20128%200%201%0Aw%20112%20128%20176%20128%200%0Ag%20336%20288%20336%20304%200%0Aw%20176%2032%20176%20128%200%0Aw%20176%20128%20176%20224%200%0Aw%20176%20288%20336%20288%200%0Aw%20416%2096%20496%2096%200%0Aw%20496%2096%20496%20192%200%0Aw%20416%20192%20496%20192%200%0Aw%20496%20192%20496%20288%200%0Aw%20416%20288%20496%20288%200%0A403%20528%2032%20656%2096%200%201_64_0_4353_1.25_0.00078125_0_2_1_3%0A403%20544%20128%20672%20192%200%204_64_0_4353_5_0.025_0_2_4_3%0A403%20560%20224%20688%20288%200%205_64_0_4353_5_0.05_3_2_5_3%0Ap%20112%20128%20112%20160%201%204%0Aw%20176%20288%20112%20288%200%0Ap%20112%20160%20112%20288%201%204%0Aw%20112%20288%2080%20288%200%0Aw%20112%20160%2080%20160%200%0Aw%2080%20128%20112%20128%200%0Ax%20271%20-8%20450%20-5%204%2014%20Only%5CsIdeal%5CsCapacitors%5Csshown%0A) how Vpp and Ipp changes at some arbitrary low frequency and fixed series resistance.

[image]